# Composite index giving me NaN

Tags: r

I'm trying to do a couple of composite indexes for my thesis. I followed this video indication (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vdmYv0YnWEE&ab_channel=DavidCaughlin)

My composite index works

```
ECEMD$indice3 <- rowMeans(ECEMD[, c("PROFSKILL_WRITESTD2", "PROFSKILL_WRITEGRANT", "PROFSKILL_PUBLISH", "PROFSKILL_HUMANETHIC", "PROFSKILL_ANIMETHIC", "PROFSKILL_IP", "PROFSKILL_PROFETHIC", "RESEXP_WRITEGRANT", "PRESPUBNUM_FUNDMEET", "PRESPUBNUM_NATLMEET", "PRESPUBNUM_PRESMEET", "PRESPUB_SEMINAR", "PRESPUBNUM_COAUTH", "PRESPUBNUM_AUTHOR", "PROFSKILL_CAREERACAD", "PROFSKILL_RESPOS")], na.rm = TRUE)
```

But as soon as I try to figure out the mean of this composite index for the total of my database or by year, it says NaN (not a number). I am 100% certain that my database contains only numbers.

```
indice3_mean <- mean(ECEMD$indice3)
```

There is alot of NA's although. What should I do?

Comment: Please provide sample data with `dput()`, e.g. `dput(mydata[1:15, ])` for the first 15 rows of the dataframe `mydata`.

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: Do any of your rows have missing values for all variables? That would trigger division by zero with na.rm=TRUE.

Comment: Yes, some observations have only NA's. How would I remove / change that?

Comment: How would something like !is.nan() work?